# Is there any version of Cauchy condensation test for integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Almost all series convergence tests has their equivalent in integral convergence test, like comparison test, asymptotic comparison test, Abel test, Dirichlet test and so on. Is there any test similiar to Cauchy condensation test applying to integral convergence?

If such thing doesn't exist, why is that?

Comment: We could always *make* such a test. Note that the integral test is an "if and only if". Thus, for a monotonically decreasing function $f:[0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$, $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n f(2^{n})$ converges if and only if $\int_0^\infty 2^x f(2^x)\,dx$ converges.

Comment: For ease of integrability, we might want to instead consider the integral $\int_0^\infty e^x f(e^x)\,dx$. Note that we can obtain a multiple of this integral from $\int_0^\infty 2^x f(2^x)\,dx$ with the substitution $x = \log_2(e) u \implies u = \ln(2) x$. So we have the following test: for a monotonically decreasing $f$, $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges iff $\int_0^\infty e^x f(e^x)\,dx$ converges.

Comment: Yes, the integral test for series

Comment: @DougL In what way is that a version of the Cauchy condensation test for integrals?

Comment: @BenGrossmann The Cauchy condensation test can be inferred from the integral test

Comment: @DougL If that's true, that would mean that the Cauchy condensation test is a *consequence of* the integral test, but that does not answer the question of how the integral test for series is *a version of* the Cauchy condensation test for integrals.